# unable to enqueue circular queue using array

Tags: c, function, queue, malloc

I am trying to enqueue data in a circular queue created using

```
struct Arrayqueue
{
    int front,rear;
    int capacity;
    int *array;
}*queue;

struct Arrayqueue* create()
{
    int data;
    struct Arrayqueue* queue=malloc(sizeof(struct Arrayqueue));
    printf("\nWrite the capacity of queue: ");
    scanf("%d",&data);
    queue->capacity=data;
    queue->front=queue->rear=-1;
    queue->array=malloc( queue->capacity * sizeof(int));
    return(queue);
}
```

I am able to process the create function. Here is my enqueue function

```
int isFull(){
    if((queue->rear+1)%queue->capacity==queue->front)
    return 1;
    else
    return 0;
}

void enqueue()
{
    int data;
    printf("Enter the data: ");
    scanf("%d",&data);
    if(!isFull()){
    queue->rear=(queue->rear+1)%queue->capacity;
    queue->array[queue->rear]=data;
    if(queue->front==-1)
    queue->front=queue->rear;
    }
    else
    printf("\nQueue is full\n");
}
```

Whenever I try to put some data, my program crashes. Where in the program is the problem?

Comment: you are not assigning pointer to malloced memory to global queue - `struct Arrayqueue* queue=malloc(sizeof(struct Arrayqueue));`  here you declare and initialize local variable. so when your scenario enters enqueue, 'queue' global is NULL.

Comment: (most likely - post entire code).